# debug script with pydev in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have used standart ide for python - IDLE for a long time. It has convinient debug. I can write script, press F5 and it is possible to use all objects in terminal.

Now i want working with eclipse and pydev plugin. Is there any similar way to debug in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.
Just start debugging - as far as I know, you have to set breakpoint, otherwise program just run to the end. And when stopped at breakpoint, in console window, click open console icon -> choose pydev console -> PyDev Debug Console.
Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The PyDev debugger should be better to work with breakpoints and in a context... See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html for basic instructions.

Note that when in a breakpoint you can simply issue commands in the console to print variables, etc.

Now, just for completeness, what IDLE has is closer to the PyDev interactive console: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html Mostly, press Ctrl+Alt+Enter in your file and it'll execute the file in a buffer for you to work interactively.